# SQL Syntax errors with commas

Tags: sql, database, trigger.io, eventtrigger, database-trigger

Complete Newb trying learn.

I want to have Table "Sales" populate Table "Finance" when the "OrderDate" is updated/entered however I am having trouble inserting multiple columns.

```
   CREATE TRIGGER SalesOrderDateTrigger
   ON [dbo].[Sales]
   AFTER INSERT
   AS
   BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @OrderDate Date

   SELECT @OrderDate = INSERTED.OrderDate FROM INSERTED

  IF @OrderDate > 0
  BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Finance 
  (Quote, Customer, Project_Name, [Value], 
  POC_Name_#1, POC_Number_#1, POC_Email_#1, 
  POC_Name_#2, POC_Number_#2, POC_Email_#2,
  Comment, [DA Link])
  SELECT (INSERTED.Quote, INSERTED.Customer, INSERTED.Project_Name, 
  INSERTED.[Value], 
  INSERTED.POC_Name_#1, INSERTED.POC_Number_#1, INSERTED.POC_Email_#1, 
  INSERTED.POC_Name_#2, INSERTED.POC_Number_#2, INSERTED.POC_Email_#2,
  INSERTED.Comment, INSERTED.[DA Link])
  FROM INSERTED

  END


 END
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Which dbms?????????????????  That's the most important info when asking question.

Comment: you don't need the () in the `SELECT`.  It should be `SELECT x, y, z`, not `SELECT (x, y, z)`

Comment: You probably wanted `SELECT @OrderDate = min(OrderDate) FROM inserted;` Or add `WHERE OrderDate > 0` to the `INSERT` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your approach..

You're not always looking at this in a "block of data" kind of way. Sure you may only insert one row at a time, but it's actually possible to insert multiple rows into a table at the same time. When this occurs, the `inserted` pseudotable will have more than one row, hence you cannot select a sole order date from it, into a single variable @orderdate. Avoid any kind of "row by row" thinking with sqlserver triggers; the design intention of sqlserver server-side programming is that it is always set based; anything you write in a trigger should handle anything from zero to millions of rows all at once, not a row at a time

I'm not really sure what the line where you compare the date with 0, is trying to achieve

You subsequently run an insert that effectively inserts data that is in the Order table, into the Finance table. No new or different data is calculated, or brought in from elsewhere, which leads me to believe that order and finance share a large number of columns, having identical data. In terms of database design, this is a poor normalisation strategy; if the finance table replicates the orders table, it probably shouldn't exist. Indeed if your business logic is that an entry in the Orders table with a non null OrderDate realises an entry in the finance table, really Finance could actually just be a `VIEW` based off of the simple query

```
SELECT blahblah FROM orders WHERE orderdate IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Ok different views...you just hit me with a wake up hammer. The best bit I actually know how to write that.

Tbh i was expecting someone like you to come around and bitch slap me with another approach.